# How to use Capistrano with Apache or Nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, deployment, nginx, capistrano

When run `cap deploy` can create some folders such as **releases** or **shared**.What's the relation between them and Apache or Nginx's server root?

Is this method right?(This is a Nginx config)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.yourhost.com;
  root /releases/...;   # Which path to be here???
  passenger_enabled on;
}
```

And also,after running `cap deploy`,can web server automatic restart?

Comment: There's at least three questions here. Please try again with a more specific question and give some indication of what you've tried and how it's (not) working.

Comment: I don't know how they works.Can you tell me how to config the nginx's config file?My question is not clear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you deploy, capistrano creates a folder in the releases folder, and then symlinks that folder to `/your_app/current`.

Since the part of your rails app that you expose to the public is the `public` folder, you need to set the root in your nginx config to:

```
root /path_to_your_app/current/public;
```

With each deploy the contents of `current` will effectively be refreshed from the source, any data not committed to the source control would be lost, and this is where the shared folder comes in. The shared folder will contain things which aren't going to be in the version control, but that you don't want to lose with each deploy - application logs, uploaded images, etc.

Here's a good example of how to use the shared folder for uploads: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/02/capistrano-uploads-folder/

Restarting the web server can be achieved with the following task in your deploy.rb:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
end
```

Phusion passenger monitors for this file, and will trigger a restart when it's created.